# How do I create the percentage once I have the Sum and Frequency of a number?

Tags: java, percentage

I am having trouble getting the percentage of the frequency. Below is the question:

Write a program to simulate the rolling of two dice. The program should use an object of class Random once to roll the first die and again to roll the second die. The sum of the two values should then be calculated. Each die can show an integer value from 1 to 6, so the sum of the values will vary from 2 to 12, with 7 being the most frequent sum and 2 and 12 being the least frequent sums.  Your application should roll the dice 36,000 times. Use a one dimensional array to keep track of the number of times each possible sum appears.
Display the results in tabular format. Determine whether the totals are reasonable (e.g., here are six ways to roll a 7, so approximately one-sixth of the rolls should be 7). 
Sample output:

```
Sum   Frequency  Percentage
  2        1027        2.85
  3        2030        5.64
  4        2931        8.14
  5        3984       11.07
  6        5035       13.99
  7        5996       16.66
  8        4992       13.87
  9        4047       11.24
 10        2961        8.23
 11        1984        5.51
 12        1013        2.81
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class DiceSum {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        int dice1, dice2;
        int [] frequency = new int [13];
        int [] rolls = new int [13];
        int sum;
        int percentage;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 36000; i++) { // runs 36000 times

            dice1 = random.nextInt(6)+1; // generates a random number
            dice2 = random.nextInt(6)+1;

            frequency[dice1+dice2]++;

            sum = dice1 + dice2; // creates the sum of dice 1 and dice 2

        }

        System.out.printf("Sum\tFrequency\tPercentage\n");

        for (int i = 2; i < frequency.length; i++) {

            percentage = (frequency * 100.0) \ 36000; //This is the line 

            System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t\n",i,frequency[i]);

        } // end of for loop

    } // end of main

} // end of class
```

Comment: For division you should use / not \ ... Then you need to take care of dividing by 36000 it will treat it as int, maybe better write it as 36000.0.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the line

```
percentage = (frequency * 100.0) \ 36000;
```

to

```
percentage = (((double)frequency[i]) * 100.0) / 36000.0;
```

frequency[i] will take the ith element from frequency.